# How do you pass all keyword-arguments to an inner function?

Tags: julia

`kwargs...` allows you to accept arbitrary keyword arguments, but you can access them in the form of a Dictionary. How do you pass all the provided keyword arguments to an inner function?

For example:

```
function bar(;kwargs...)
    print(kwargs)
end

function foo(;kwargs...)
    bar(<MODIFY ME>)
end
```

How do I modify the call to bar such that it receives all the keyword arguments passed into foo?

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
function foo(;kwargs...)
    bar(;kwargs...)
end
```

(note the semicolon before `kwargs`)

Comment: It's a semicolon :)